# SPI or I2C? Termonology questions

Tags: linux

Please help me understand why SPI and I2C SOMETIME describes SAME serial / synchronous protocol?
On Raspberry Pi the "ports" are "labeled" SDA / SCL - two wire (serial) protocol. 
Please no references to "what is SPI /I2C?", just seeking clarification / comment on the above SPECIFIC  question.

PS 
Does "S" in SDA / SCL stands for serial or synchronous?
Given the hardware it cannot be parallel, so is "serial" redundant?

Thanks for replies.

Comment: I just think this isn't the correct site for your question, please try [RPi stackexchange](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/) or [ElectricalEngineering stackexchange](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/). By the way: nice question.

Comment: Where have you seen SPI and I2C used to describe the same protocol? Since, you know, they are different protocols.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SPI and I2C are very different protocols (have a look at the Wikipedia description). They even have a different number of lines: Clock and data for I2C, and SCLK, MISO, MOSI and SS for SPI. And the pinouts for the Raspberry Pi B I've also use names like `SPI_MOSI`, `SPI_MOSI` and `SPI_SCLK`.

There is a protocol which is very similar (so similar it can be viewed as a kind of subset) to I2C called SMBus. Maybe you mean that instead of SPI?

That said, on embdedded SoC's like the one on the Raspberry Pi, pins of often multi-purpose, and can be reassigned to different parts of the chip (e.g. I2C controller vs. SPI controller, or even UART ...) by writing to special registers. Which is why you see particular pins used in different roles. And of course, if you use them in different, but similar roles, it makes sense to reassign them in such a way that their purpose is similar.

I've no idea if the developers of the SoC meant "serial" or "synchronous" when they named the SDA and SCL pins, and I guess it really doesn't matter ... and unless you read through the SoC documentation and get lucky and find a place where the spell out the abbreviation, it will probably remain a mystery.

Comment: What actually prompted me to ask – I run into sample code setting MODE to 0 in I2C protocol. 
There in no “MODE” the data is always updated on trailing edge of the clock.
I think l I need to take a look at the SMbus.
BTW the S in SPI  does stands for “serial” which to me seems redundant. 
Thanks